How to make emacs show what it's doing when a loop is executing?
I have a LaTeX file with many URLs, so I wanto to check if they are OK with url-http-file-exists-p programmatically.
My idea is to extract all the URLs from the main buffer and put them in a buffer called *URLs* side by side with the main one. Now in the *URLs* buffer emacs should check every URL with url-http-file-exists-p and put the string "works" or "DOES NOT work" side by side to it.
I can do everything I've described, except make emacs show me what it's doing step by step when the loop is executing.
Here is my function:
(defun buffer-urls-check ()
  "Check if URLs in a buffer works or not (bibliography excluded)."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((case-fold-search nil)
         (preprint-id (current-buffer)))

    ;; clear *URLs* buffer
    (when (get-buffer "*URLs*")
      (switch-to-buffer-other-window "*URLs*")
      (delete-region (point-min) (point-max))
      (switch-to-buffer-other-window preprint-id))

    ;; get \href{} [no bib]
    ;; get \url{}  [no bib]
    (let ((thini (progn
                   (goto-char (point-min))
                   (re-search-forward "\\\\begin{thebibliography}")
                   (match-beginning 0))))

      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (re-search-forward "\\\\\\(href\\|url\\){" thini t)
        (save-excursion
          (let* ((pos1 (copy-marker (match-end 0)))
                 (pos2 (copy-marker (progn
                                      (backward-char 1)
                                      (forward-sexp)
                                      (backward-char 1)
                                      (point))))
                 (url (buffer-substring-no-properties pos1 pos2)))

            (switch-to-buffer-other-window "*URLs*")
            (goto-char (point-max))
            (insert (concat url "\n"))
            (switch-to-buffer-other-window preprint-id))))

      ;; delete repeated URLs
      (switch-to-buffer-other-window "*URLs*")
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (re-search-forward "^\\(.+\\)" nil t)
        (save-excursion
          (let* ((thini (copy-marker (match-end 0)))
                 (url (match-string 0)))

            (while (re-search-forward (concat "^"
                                              url
                                              "$")
                                      nil t)
              (delete-region (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position))))))

      ;; delete empty lines
      (flush-lines "^$" (point-min) (point-max))

      ;; check URLs
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (re-search-forward "^\\(.+\\)$" nil t)
        (save-excursion
          (cond
           ((url-http-file-exists-p (match-string 0))
            (insert ": works"))
           (t
            (insert ": DOES NOT work")))))

      (switch-to-buffer-other-window preprint-id))))

The buffer *URLs* is shown after emacs has finished to execute my function, but I want that the buffer *URLs* appears before emacs initializes the while loop so that I can see the results ("works" or "DOES NOT work") appear progressively with each iteration.
I tried using y-or-n-p as a workaround to make the *URLs* buffer appear before the loop executes, i.e.
  (when (y-or-n-p "Start checking URLs? (y or n) ")
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (re-search-forward "^\\(.+\\)$" nil t)
      (save-excursion
        (cond
         ((url-http-file-exists-p (match-string 0))
          (insert ": works"))
         (t
          (insert ": DOES NOT work"))))))

and it works, but it's an annoying trick. However, even so emacs does not progressively show what it is doing, so it's useless.
How can I make emacs show me every iteration of the loop above in the buffer-urls-check function?
Attempt 1
Reading @NickD suggestion, I rewrote my function as it follows:
(defun buffer-urls-check-ver1 ()
  "Check if URLs in a buffer works or not (bibliography excluded)."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((case-fold-search nil)
         (preprint-id (current-buffer)))

    ;; clear *URLs* buffer
    (when (get-buffer "*URLs*")
      (switch-to-buffer-other-window "*URLs*")
      (delete-region (point-min) (point-max))
      (switch-to-buffer-other-window preprint-id))

    ;; get \href{} [no bib]
    ;; get \url{}  [no bib]
    (let ((thini (progn
                   (goto-char (point-min))
                   (re-search-forward "\\\\begin{thebibliography}")
                   (match-beginning 0))))
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (re-search-forward "\\\\\\(href\\|url\\){" thini t)
        (save-excursion
          (let* ((pos1 (copy-marker (match-end 0)))
                 (pos2 (copy-marker (progn
                                      (backward-char 1)
                                      (forward-sexp)
                                      (backward-char 1)
                                      (point))))
                 (url (buffer-substring-no-properties pos1 pos2)))

            ;; check if URL is valid
            (switch-to-buffer-other-window "*URLs*")
            (cond
             ((url-http-file-exists-p url)
              (goto-char (point-max))
              (insert (concat url ": works\n")))
             (t
              (insert (concat url ": DOES NOT work\n"))))
            (switch-to-buffer-other-window preprint-id)))))

    ;; delete repeated URLs
    (switch-to-buffer-other-window "*URLs*")
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (re-search-forward "^\\(.+\\)" nil t)
      (save-excursion
        (let* ((thini (copy-marker (match-end 0)))
               (url (match-string 0)))

          (perform-replace url "" nil t nil 1 nil thini (point-max)))))

    ;; delete empty lines
    (flush-lines "^$" (point-min) (point-max))))

This function does not work as I expected: it behaves like buffer-urls-check, i.e. the buffer *URLs* is shown after emacs has finished to execute it and so I can't see the results "works" or "DOES NOT work" appear progressively with each iteration.
I'm starting to think that the problem could be url-http-file-exists-p. If I replace the first condition in cond with something like this
(cond
 ((string-match-p "google" url)
  (goto-char (point-max))
  (insert (concat url ": works\n")))
 (t
  (goto-char (point-max))
  (dotimes (i 10)
    (insert (concat url ": DOES NOT work\n")))))

the buffer *URL* is shown and you can see every iteration.
Here is a test file:
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\url{http://www.thai-language.com/}

\url{https://www.thai2english.com/}

\url{https://th.wikipedia.org/}

\url{https://www.debian.org/}

\url{https://www.google.com}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}


You'll need to check each URL as it is entered in the buffer, i.e. you'll need to combine the first and last loops into a single loop (and the optimizations will not be done until the end.)

@NickD Tried your solution, but it does not work. I think or I'm not using url-http-file-exists-p correctly or the problem is really url-http-file-exists-p...

"does not work" doesn't tell us anything: how does it not work? Are there error messages? You need to provide all available information.

@NickD Sorry, I didn't explain myself well: I meant that it doesn't behave as I expected it would. I edited my question to explain myself better.

Redisplay is independent of buffer changes.  When Emacs has a reason/opportunity to update the display, it does it at that time, based on (a) what it was previously displaying in that window, and (b) what the current contents of that window need to be.  Any number of buffer changes might have taken place in between display cycles.  You can force a redisplay by calling (redisplay).

It's exactly what I was looking for: I put (redisplay) after cond in buffer-urls-check-ver1 and now I can see all the iterations one by one.
